# How can I use external modem for voice calls on Android tablet?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, sms, tablet, calls, usb-modem

My tablet doesn't support calling/messaging function by default and also it doesn't have an app for that by default.

Is it possible? In my case I use Micromax Infinity P275 tablet and Huawei E1732 modem. ICS is my OS. I can connect to the internet with that modem.

Comment: That's very much possible (I have such tablets as well). There are USB dongles available to provide access to the mobile network world (usually called "UMTS sticks" or the like, at least here in Europe). You might look out for them and, to check compatibility, take your tab with you to a store selling them to "try before buy". Note: You will most likely need an OTG cable to connect them.

Comment: i have made calls with this modem from my laptop/Win8. Is there an app available ?

Comment: I don't know that Huawei modem you mention. Does it connect to the mobile network, or landline? In the latter case it's unlikely to work with Android. In the former case, it might still be incompatible. You could check with the tablet vendor if there are recommended "UMTS sticks", or even might be "tricks" to get the Huawei modem to work with the tablet.

Comment: I can connect to the internet with that modem. If i root my tablet any chance of getting this done?

Answer (score -1):

Root your phone, and download [PPP Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.draisberghof.pppwidget&hl=en) from Google Play.

Comment: How will this solve the problem?